# Issue with array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml, android-resources

I have a method leftup which has an onClick listener from a button. The purpose of method leftup is to do the following:

1. Get an array from resources xml
   (Which contains names of my other activities)
2. Turn array into an array list
3. Remove a string from that array
   (The current class name)
4. Convert the list back into an array
5. Get a random value from that array
6. Execute method goToActivity with parameter of that random value

**I have spent hours on this task so far,** because the logic of the code seems fine. The problem is, when I run the code, I get the infamous error:

```
Unfortunately, "App_Name" has stopped
```

Here is my code for method onClick and goToActivity:

[image: OnClick and goToActivity]

Here is my array in the resources:

[image]

**By the way, string activity state is the name of the activity :**

[image]

I am sure the exception is in the method leftup, as none of the Toasts get executed, and the error happens immediately as I click on the button.

Thank you so much for all your help, I really appreciate it.

A fellow programmer,

```
{Rich}
```

Stack trace:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dcd63f51289aaf1a1933

Here is the stack trace because I couldn't format it, this is the git hub page.

Comment: Post your logcat output. It will tell you the exception, the source of the exception, the line where it came from...

Comment: @takendarkk Hey, thanks for your reply! I am pretty sure the exception is in this method, as none of the Toasts get executed, and the error happens immediately as I click on the button.

Comment: Rich, the logcat only where the stacktrace appeared. That thing with "java.exception" or something like that, usually in red, with some lines and file names together. Example: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/screen-shot-2010-03-17-at-100031-am.png

Comment: @GeorgeRappel How do I get to that? I have looked it up, but cannot find it.

Comment: [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Comment: No you have not. Not only can I not see it in your question but the last edit on your question was 27 minutes ago.

Comment: @takendarkk It says that I have to format it. I am trying to format the code properly. I had posted that comment thinking I would post the stack trace right after. I am sorry for any confusions

Comment: @takendarkk https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dcd63f51289aaf1a1933

Comment: @takendarkk Here is the stack trace.

Comment: @takendarkk According to it, this may be the error... arrayList.remove(activityState);

Comment: @takendarkk But I can't see what's wrong with it. Logically it makes sense. Thanks

Comment: @GeorgeRappel  gist.github.com/anonymous/dcd63f51289aaf1a1933

Comment: See, all you have to do is read the stacktrace :) Also, next time paste your code in text, not prints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! After three long hours of tweaking the code, I finally got it! The arrayList had to be a linkedList. **Thats it!** Because, arrayList's aren't as flexible, and so one cannot remove or add items to them. I hope this answer helps, and saves you three long hours!

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

are the exceptions that happen on this issue.  Just make sure to use a more flexible container. :)

```
{Rich}
```